# SQL Query: Cascading "Managers" query problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a database of employees and their direct manager. Each employee row has a ManagerId column. If I run a report to see which employees report to "Bob", I get a list of employees with "Bob's" Id in the ManagerId column. This is fine for finding out who reports directly to Bob but I want to see everyone that reports to Bob or any of the directors, managers, or supervisors that report to Bob.

How do I do this?

Edit 1 - This is for SQL Server 2005 / 2008. I'd like all employees under Bob, not just those reporting directly to him.

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using?

Comment: I can't ascertain what your issue is. So you can get all the employees that report to Bob, but you can't get employees that are directors, managers or supervisors that also report to Bob?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer - He wants recursive hierarchy basically.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer He wants to see all of Bob's subordinates, even if they're not *direct* subordinates (i.e. He wants to see Mitch, who reports to Alice, who reports to Fred, who reports to Bob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, in recent versions of SQL Server, you can accomplish this via a recursive Common Table Expression.

See [this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/databasedesign/thread/524ecdfd-d8be-4d8c-9701-f9a89f8f942e/) and its answers. To quote:

```
WITH EmpCTE(empid, empname, mgrid, IsRoot)
AS
(

 -- Anchor Member (AM)
 SELECT empid, empname, mgrid, CASE WHEN mgrid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsRoot
 FROM Employees
 WHERE empid = @empid

 UNION ALL

 -- Recursive Member (RM)
 SELECT M.empid, M.empname, M.mgrid, CASE WHEN M.mgrid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM Employees AS M
  JOIN EmpCTE AS E
   ON E.mgrid = M.empid
)
SELECT * FROM EmpCTE
GO
```

That'll give you a starting point.

Comment: The aliasing is giving me headaches - `E for Manager` and `M for Employee`?

Comment: Note the join criterion: The record from `M` *is* the manager. It's sort of a reverse example of the OP's scenario, but the technique stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using hierarchical queries if your database supports it. Which Database are you using.

For Oracle : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

For SQL Server (and I believe the ANSI SQL Syntax is also supported for Oracle from 11g R2), check this link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: You've got the same link in there twice, kiddo. :)